# How can I make a remote server "appear" on the local network?

Tags: networking, vpn, bridge

I have a media server on my home network to which I can open ports as needed.  For example, I can SSH into it from outside the home network.  When traveling I'd like to use my laptop connected to the local network to make the media server "appear" on the local network so that things on the local network, such as a Roku, can discover services on the media server, such as DLNA.  To my ears this sounds something like a reverse VPN and I assume it would involve some sort of network bridging on the local side.

I can install software as needed on both the remote media server and my local laptop, such as OpenVPN, etc..  Both the server and laptop are running Linux.

Comment: Which OS are you using on your laptop?

Comment: I added the OS, Linux.

Comment: You can use putty to establish a tunnel to the remove server; the tunnel can then be accessed via `localhost`; of course, this does nothing for network discovery, and other computers on your LAN cannot use the tunnel

Comment: And discovery is the core of the question.

Comment: You pretty much answered your own question. Openvpn would work well here. Make it easy for yourself and install it at the router level.

Comment: No, @Tim_Stewart, per the question, I am looking for the *reverse* of the typical OpenVPN usage.

Comment: How do you use OpenVPN when you're on the road to make the OpenVPN *server* appear as a local presence on the network you're at "on the road", @Tim_Stewart?

Comment: You use a VPN client to reach the tunnel network you created on your server. In this case you want the tunnel network as a portion of your home servers network address range.(bridged) or you won't be able to scan for media servers. Don't use a virtual IP pool.

Comment: The reason I said bridge, is because I don't think DLNA works across network broadcast domains. Don't pin me down to that, I have heard you can do it under special circumstances by setting up special rules etc. I never confirmed it because it was really easy to get going bridged.